# Merge cells together in 'xlsx-populate' module for node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx-populate

I am using [xlsx-populate](https://github.com/dtjohnson/xlsx-populate#Range+merged) module for making excel file, but I need merged some row and column together and set value to this. Anyone help to me for making this excel file?

for example merge `merge(A1, C3)` and add my value into big row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of creating merged cells using the [xlsl-populate](https://github.com/dtjohnson/xlsx-populate) module.

We create 2 sets of merged cells, I think this give you a good idea of how to proceed:

```
const XlsxPopulate = require('xlsx-populate');

async function testMerge() {
    let workbook = await XlsxPopulate.fromBlankAsync();

    // Create a range of merged cells.
    const range = workbook.sheet(0).range("A1:C3");
    range.value("We are merged!!");
    range.style({horizontalAlignment: "center", verticalAlignment: "center", })
    range.merged(true);

    // Create another range of merged cells.
    const range2 = workbook.sheet(0).range("D1:F3");
    range2.value("We are also merged!!");
    range2.style({horizontalAlignment: "center", verticalAlignment: "center", })
    range2.merged(true);

    // Write to the output file.
    await workbook.toFileAsync("./out.xlsx");
}

testMerge();
```